# sum of amount not working by using ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try this format but its not working

**

```
"name": [{
  "id": 3,
  "qty": 2
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "qty": 5
}]
```

**
This is my function once after get response on keyup qty textbox i want to add all amount in one textbox and show all entered value id and qty in above mention format

```
function _getPriceCalculation() {
            var sum = 0;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $('#categoryList').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        $('<div id="price_calculation"><div class="col-lg-4 main"><input type="text" value="'+item.name+'" readonly class="form-control"/></div><div class="col-lg-4 main" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="id" id="price-'+item.id+'" value="'+item.price+'" readonly class="form-control" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></div><div class="col-lg-4 main"><input type="text" value="" name="qty" id="qty-'+item.id+'" class="form-control qty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></div><div class="col-lg-4 main"><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount-'+item.id+'" value="" readonly class="form-control amount" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/></div>').appendTo("#price-calculation-view");    
                        $("#qty-"+item.id).keyup(function(){
                            var qty = $("#qty-"+item.id).val();
                            var price = $("#price-"+item.id).val();
                            var total = qty * price;
                            $("#amount-"+item.id).val(total);
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

        }

$(document).on("keyup", "input[name='qty']", function() {
    //$('input[name="qty"]').change(function(){
       // alert();
      var name = [];
      $('.main').each(function(index,item){
        var obj={};
        obj.id = $(item).find('input[name="id"]').val();
        obj.qty = $(item).find('input[name="qty"]').val();
        name.push(obj)
      });
      console.log(name);
});
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: url: $('#categoryList').val(). you are keeping target url in some element value?

Comment: When is the function `_getPriceCalculation` called?

Comment: It will call on page loag load

Answer (score 1):

`$("#qty-"+item.id)` **DOM** elements are added **dynamically** on the page.

You have to use `event delegation` for elements which were added **dynamically**.

You should bind **keyup** event handler using `.on()` method.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#qty-'+item.id, function(){
     var qty = $("#qty-"+item.id).val();
     var price = $("#price-"+item.id).val();
     var total = qty * price;
     $("#amount-"+item.id).val(total);
});
```

Comment: I want all amount total in one textbox

Comment: I want to show total amount in result text box Sum of all amount value

Comment: Then just use `each` method and sum the amounts.